# SIGABRT:out of range when using stoi/stol

Tags: c++, sigabrt

//I'm trying to solve this problem from `HackerEarth`: Binary Queries.

Though initially, the problem sounds easy to me but when actually submitted my code to run on all the test cases, my code is throwing `SIGABRT error`.

Upon checking the error, I found the error to be of type `out of range`. I'm unable to figure out how to resolve this:
problem: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/arrays/1-d/practice-problems/algorithm/range-query-2/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cctype>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    long N,Q,L,R,X;
    int ch=0,buf;
    unsigned long long intrim;
    string str,cstr;

    scanf("%ld %ld",&N,&Q);
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,str);
    str.erase((remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),(int(*)(int))isspace)),str.end()); // here its a key point
    //cout<<str;

    for(int i=0;i<Q;i++)
    { 
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        if(ch==1) // alter the X bit
        { 
            scanf("%ld",&X);

            if(str[X-1]==0){ 
                str[X-1]=1;
            }
            else {
                     str[X-1]=0;
                 }
        }
        else if(ch==0)
             { 
                 scanf("%ld %ld",&L,&R); 
                 cstr.append((str.begin()+L-1),str.begin()+R);
                 intrim=std::stoull(cstr,nullptr,2);
                 if(intrim%2==0){ 
                     cout<<"EVEN"<<endl;
                 }
                 else{ 
                         cout<<"ODD"<<endl;
                     }
                 cstr.clear();
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you actually provide a test case that replicates the error? Because the only example given at your link runs fine.

Comment: As an aside, if you're going to write C++ and use iostreams, it seems odd to fill your code with `scanf` calls. Reading items from `std::cin` is straightfoward and the internet has many examples for you.

Comment: Hi Rook, Thanks for replying!  But isn't the scanf() faster then cin? please find the test case here for which SIGABRT RE is generated:      https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/codering/problems/cf972712-8-in00.txt?Signature=6g2REPAaJZmZ7vHPi66%2BK%2BB0lgw%3D&Expires=1495204724&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ

Comment: There is no way that the speed of cin will affect your program ;-) Premature optimisation is the root of all evil; don't do it. iostreams are more than fast enough for your needs, and `scanf` is an easy function to use incorrectly.

Comment: The AWS link you generated has expired. Please put any important information into the your original question so everyone will be able to see it!

Comment: Thanks for the information will take care about in future, the test cases are big enough I'll soon share the google drive link here.  Rook but one more clarification I need, today I submitted my program using C++ stdin/stdout, and there I got TLE for few test cases, but as soon as I changed cin with scanf the program run swiftly. So any specific info regarding this behavior?

Comment: Either you've used `cin` in some very strange, very bad way, or the platform your code is building and running on uses a very strange, broken stream implementation. Without being able to see your code and run test cases against it, it is impossible for me to say more.

Answer (score 0):

**stoi** return an integer number

**stol** return a long int number

**stoll** return a long long int number

So, when you are converting a string to a number, thought about the possible range and use accordingly.